# Методы защиты информационной системы

Tags: защита

Возник вопрос о том, как предоставить абстрактной информационной системе защищённость?

Я понимаю такие банальные способы как разграничение прав, шифрование или система идентификации, однако может существует что-то поинтереснее? В интернете уже искал, но основу, которую я подчеркнул, я уже предоставил.

Comment: Вы не искали хорошо структурированные учебники для ВУЗов по этой теме, которые одобрены Министерством? Скорее всего, лучшие и развёрнытые ответы будут там. Не представляю, каким может быть короткий практически применимый ответ. Хотя учитывая предыдущий ваш вопрос, есть у меня подозрение, что вы ищете какой-то волшебный простой и одновременно суперзащищённый метод. Если так, то такой вы не найдёте.

Comment: Отключить от сети и поставить взвод автоматчиков